# Get HTML tags in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
<html xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>View Health Report</title>
<head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I have an HTMl like above, it is inserted inside an iframe. So I have selenium code like below:

```
//get iframe
WebDriver frame = getFrame()// Brings iframe driver
WebElement html = frame.findElement( By.tagName("html") );// works fine I can see HTMl text from html.getText();

//now try to get title
WebElement title = html.findElement( By.tagName("title"));//title.getText() is always empty.
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Try `title.getAttribute("innerHTML");`

Comment: Modify this line `WebElement title = html.findElement( By.tagName("title"));` with `WebElement title = frame.findElement( By.tagName("title"));`

Comment: Thanks @RafałLaskowski, it worked

Comment: @user987316 I added this comment as answer. Please, accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `title.getAttribute("innerHTML");`

Answer (score 0):

for Title you can use `driver.getTitle();`

Answer (score 0):

As you see your page only display the title of main page in browser title bar, the title of page inside frame will be invisible. For invisible element, `getText()` will return empty string.

You should use `getAttribute('textContent')` which work both on visible and  invisible element. But not use it abuse, generally use getText() to close to user experience as more as possible.